# Confusion with module and model name in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces

I have a full CRUD system implemented for `Customer` in the project. The path for the `customers_controller.rb` is

```
app/controllers/admin/customers_controller.rb
```

On top of it, i have to add new feature so i created a new controller `feature_controller.rb` (name changed) with a file path like this

```
app/controllers/admin/customer/features_controller.rb
```

**Code inside the controller**

```
module Admin
  module Customer
    class FeatureController < ApplicationController
      def index; end
    end
  end
end
```

So it has some how affected my old functionalities as when i normally create customer it is reporting this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for Admin::Customer:Module):
  app/controllers/admin/customers_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

and the line number 21 is:

```
@customer = Customer.new customer_params
if @customer.save
....
```

I then removed the **new controller and the folder as well**  but still the same error.

I looked out the type of `Customer` class in `binding.pry` and it is saying that it is a `Module`.

**UPDATE**
**development.rb**

```
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false
```

**application.rb**

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/*"].select{|f| File.directory? f}
```

Comment: anybody have any idea about it ?

Comment: Since you are having trouble with seeing old code, try turning off dev caching. Since this question is months recent, you might be using Rails 5 and Puma. `rails server --help`. Try this command: `rails server --no-dev-caching`.

Answer (score 2):

Use constant resolution operator (`::`).

```
@customer = ::Customer.new customer_params
```

will solve it for you, because this way you tell rails to look for the `Customer` constant outside the current scope.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what's problem and how the solution helps?

Comment: Then i have to make changes all over the place in the old code. I've already removed the new controller from the project but it is still conflicting with it. Do you know why ?

Comment: @Ahmadhamza I think it has something to with constants autoloading. Try to restart the server and spring.

Comment: I guessed the same and restarted the system as well. But no luck. I tried to stop the spring but it is saying `Spring is not running`

Comment: @Ahmadhamza search for some config settings regarding autoloading in development mode

Comment: @AndreyDeineko i have updated the question with development.rb and application.rb code. I dont think it has anything to do with it.

Comment: @Ahmadhamza you have `config.eager_load` set to `false`. Try switching to `true`. Restart the server after making this change.